# Displaying Cards in Python with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on school project where I have to display  cards in a memory matching format (ie there will be 2 threes of Hearts and 2 fours of Spades.)

The else statement in newGame is where I'm trying to put the code to display the cards. Where I am lost at, is what I need to add so that the cards will show in a manner such that there are 2 matching . I also have images of all the cards in a folder. (Including the back image)

I've tried looking on github and on here as well, but I'm having trouble finding what I need. I know how to display 1 card or more, but not in a "2d list" type of way.

Here's the code for my project so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import random

class Card(object):
    RANKS = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
    SUITS = ("Spades", 'Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs')
    BACK_Name = "DECK/b.gif"

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        """Creates a card with the given rank and suit."""
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.fileName = 'DECK/' + str(rank) + suit[0] + '.gif'

    def getFace(self):
        return self.face

    def setFace(self, value):
        self.face = value

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns the string representation of a card."""
        if self.rank == 1:
            rank = 'Ace'
        elif self.rank == 11:
            rank = 'Jack'
        elif self.rank == 12:
            rank = 'Queen'
        elif self.rank == 13:
            rank = 'King'
        else:
            rank = self.rank
        return str(rank) + ' of ' + self.suit

class Deck(object):
    """ A deck containing 52 cards."""

    def __init__(self, numberOfPairs):
        """Creates a full deck of cards."""
        self._cards = []
        for suit in Card.SUITS:
            for rank in Card.RANKS:
                c1 = Card(rank, suit)
                self._cards.append(c1)
                c2 = Card(rank, suit)
                self._cards.append(c2)

    def shuffle(self):
        """Shuffles the cards."""
        random.shuffle(self._cards)

    def deal(self):
        """Removes and returns the top card or None 
        if the deck is empty."""
        if len(self) == 0:
           return None
        else:
           return self._cards.pop(0)

    def __len__(self):
       """Returns the number of cards left in the deck."""
       return len(self._cards)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns the string representation of a deck."""
        self.result = ''
        for c in self._cards:
            self.result = self.result + str(c) + '\n'
        return self.result

class TheGame(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Memory Matching Game")
        self.grid()

        self.deck = Deck()
        self.BackImage = PhotoImage(file = Card.BACK_Name)

        '''Row Entry Label and Box'''
        self.rowLabel = Label(self, text = "Number of Rows")
        self.rowLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.rowVar = IntVar()
        self.rowVar.set(2)
        self.rowEntry = Entry(self, textvariable = self.rowVar)
        self.rowEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        '''Column Entry Label and Box'''
        self.columnLabel = Label(self, text = "Number of Columns")
        self.columnLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        self.columnVar = IntVar()
        self.columnVar.set(2)
        self.columnEntry = Entry(self, textvariable = self.columnVar)
        self.columnEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 3)

        self.button1 = Button(self, text = "New Game", command = self.newGame)
        self.button1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

        self.button2 = Button(self, text = "Turn Over", command = self.turnOver)
        self.button2.grid(row = 1, column = 2, columnspan = 2)

    def newGame(self):
        numberOfPairs = self.columnVar.get() * self.rowVar.get() // 2
        suit = random.choice(['s', 'c', 'd', 'h'])
        deck = Deck(numberOfPairs)
        deck.shuffle()

        if self.columnVar.get() * self.rowVar.get() > 20:
            showerror(message = "Number of rows X number of columns cannot exceed 20",
                                   parent = self)
        elif self.columnVar.get() * self.rowVar.get() %2 != 0:
            showerror(message = "Number of rows X number of columns must be even",
                                   parent = self)
        else:


    def turnOver(self):
        pass

def main():
    TheGame().mainloop()


main()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched on GitHub.com for solutions?  I know there are several good examples there, and you could get the display code from the posted solutions.  A lot of people have done this before you.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Style comments: the getface and setface functions are useless, and against Python style.  The \__str__ function should use a dict to map special ranks to names.